# Python3 Object with an object in its list takes longer to call than one without

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Question: For some strange reason, `get_dispChar` takes nearly 400 milliseconds to call only when `resourceList` has 1 or more Resource object in it. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

My class TerrainTile has the following constructor

```
class TerrainTile:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tileX = 0               #world x coord
        self.tileY = 0               #world y coord
        self.elevation = 0           #int from 0-100, tells how high the highest point on the tile is
        self.symbol = '?'
        self.fgCol = [0,0,0,0]
        self.bkCol = [0,0,0,0]
        self.resourceList = []       #list of resource objects
        self.buildingList = []       #list of building objects
        self.accessibility = 0       #int from 0 - 128 determing maximum building size total on plot
        self.highestDispPriority = 0 #for displaying resources or buildings
        return
```

`self.symbol` is determined by the following:

```
# determine if a resource OR building on the tile has a more important symbol and color to display
    for rs in self.resourceList:
        if(int(rs.get_dispPriority()) > self.highestDispPriority):
            self.fgCol = rs.get_color()
            self.symbol = rs.get_symbol()
    return
```

And the symbol retrieved from this function:

```
def get_dispChar (self):
    #print("Printing: ",self.symbol)
    return self.symbol
```

For some strange reason, `get_dispChar` takes nearly 400 milliseconds to call only when `resourceList` has 1 or more Resource object in it. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? The resource object definition gets a little bit complicated because I load from a xml file, but here is the constructor for the Resource class.

```
#initialization of Resource
def __init__(self, name, itemID, companyID, quantity, volumePerUnit, valuePerUnit, color, symbol, dispPriority, isDiscovered):
    self.name = name
    self.itemID = itemID
    self.companyID = companyID
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.volumePerUnit = volumePerUnit
    self.valuePerUnit = valuePerUnit
    self.color = color
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.dispPriority = dispPriority
    self.isDiscovered = isDiscovered
```

Ill be constantly refreshing the page so should be able to provide whatever code snippets. Yes I know my code is spaghetti autism and am more than open to improvement suggestions unrelated to the question.

Thank you in advance!

Ill go through and do timing tests if y'all need em

Here is a quick time table for how long it takes to call get_dispChar from TerrainTiles

```
#Moving into main game loop
0.0                      #how long it takes to call get_dispChar when the object does NOT have an object in resourceList
0.6212029457092285       #how long it takes to call get_dispChar when the object DOES have an object in resourceList
```

Comment: You should loop over `for rs in self.resourceList:` instead of `for counter in range(len(self.resourceList)):` and replace all those `self.resourceList[counter]` by `rs`. More readable, faster, more pythonic :)

Comment: @Eskapp Thank you for the tip! I will change that, any other suggestions? I come from a c++ background so python has been a bit odd for me to pickup, not use to things being so pseudo-codey

Comment: As it is `if(len(self.resourceList) > 0):` is useless. I mean, the code will have the same behavior with or without.

Comment: @Eskapp Thank you for being an actually kind stackOverflow user, I remember when I was first getting into C++ getting crap in the comments and responses because I was new and my code wasn't pretty. And again thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: We need to see a [mcve]. I'm particularly interested in how you timed this; it doesn't sound like `get_dispChar` is the part that's taking all that time.

Comment: @user2357112 The error was in how I loaded from a .xml file. I am extremely new to everything .xml and didn't recognize it loads all data as strings. Turns out the strings borked a method I was using and the values had to be converted to ints before they could be used. Thanks for trying to help anyways!

Comment: @JCline can you please remove your answer from the question, and post it as an actual answer? It would better suite the QA format of this site.

Answer (score -2):

## SOLUTION

I have found the solution! To create the color list I pull data from a .xml file shown here>

```
<collection col = "resources">
    <item name='lumber'>
        <itemId>1</itemId>
        <volumePerUnit>5</volumePerUnit>
        <valuePerUnit>10</valuePerUnit>
        <symbol>T</symbol>
        <color1>255</color1>
        <color2>138</color2>
        <color3>88</color3>
        <color4>38</color4>
        <dispPriority>5</dispPriority>
        <isDiscovered>1</isDiscovered>
    </item>
</collection>
```

When I pulled the value color[n] from the .xml file, I was pulling it as a string rather than an integer. Shown here:

```
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color1')[0]
color[0] = fgCol.childNodes[0].data
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color2')[0]
color[1] = fgCol.childNodes[0].data
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color3')[0]
color[2] = fgCol.childNodes[0].data
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color4')[0]
color[3] = fgCol.childNodes[0].data
```

It turns out python3 doesn't like to tell the user when a string is being used rather than an int. The function I used to convert the list into a usable color type required intergers rather than strings. To fix this I added `int()` to the values to get this:

```
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color1')[0]
color[0] = int(fgCol.childNodes[0].data)
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color2')[0]
color[1] = int(fgCol.childNodes[0].data)
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color3')[0]
color[2] = int(fgCol.childNodes[0].data)
fgCol = item.getElementsByTagName('color4')[0]
color[3] = int(fgCol.childNodes[0].data)
```

## What to take away from this as a reader

The `time` module in python is a literal life saver. I used it to track how long every operation in my code took until I found the one hogging the computing time.

In order to make this question productive for those in the future, please use the `time` module!! Here was my code with the problem:

```
terminal.color(finForCol)
terminal.bkcolor(finBackCol)
terminal.put(cursorX, cursorY, symbol)
```

It turns out the method `terminal.color()` method bugs out when given a list of strings rather than integers. I would have never found this if I did not test the timings on each operation. Thank you to those who help and I will still gladly take suggestions to improve my code, thank you!